# How to run datawig on GPU?

Tags: python, data-science, mxnet, imputation

I tried to run Imputer.fit by passing mxnet.context with gpu id but it seems mycode still run on cpu.

```
from mxnet import gpu
...
ctx = gpu(0)
...
imputer.fit(train_df=imputer_train_df, num_epochs=10, ctx=ctx)
```

Anyone know how to correctly do this ?
I understand that mxnet doesn't support cuda 11.0 that I use now.

Is there a way to run datawig on GPU ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error/warning message? GPU support is MXNet based, so having a compatible versions should be a requirement.